# Cannot create multiline statement blocks in ipython3 on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, ipython

I can't figure out what it is but the ipython repl does not accept multiline statement blocks. For ex., when I try to write a for loop, I can only enter the first line after the loop statement but subsequently pressing enter simply executes the statement instead of allowing another line.

```
In [2]: if x == 0:
   ...:     print(x)
0
```

I'm unable to extend the for loop by entering more lines in that block.

What is strange is that, if I use ipython v5 (which uses python 2.7), I don't have this problem. It only seems to be specific to ipython3

I'm on macOS Mojave, in iTerm2 (although I have the same problem in terminal as well)

I've tried installing ipython3 via `pip3 install ipython` and ipython via homebrew `brew install ipython`, but nothing seems to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: What version of ipython are you using? There is a [bug affecting multiline editing in ipython version 7](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11334)

Comment: Version 7.0.1. Thanks for the link, that's exactly it. I was thinking it was an issue with my setup.

Answer (score 0):

As [myrtlecat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673733/cannot-create-multiline-statement-blocks-in-ipython3-on-macos#comment92277347_52673733) pointed out in the comments above, this is in fact a [bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11334) with IPython v7.0.1.